# pandas Series' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to do simple plot of data and getting the following error.. any help is very much appreciated

**AttributeError:** 'Series' object has no attribute 'find'

**Versions :**
python3 ,
matplotlib (2.0.2) ,
pandas (0.20.3) ,
jupyter (1.0.0).

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pd_hr_data = pd.read_csv("/Users/pc/Downloads/HR_comma_sep.csv")

#print(pd_hr_data['average_montly_hours'],pd_hr_data['sales'])
take_ten_data = pd_hr_data[0:19]
x = take_ten_data['average_montly_hours'].astype(int)
y = take_ten_data['sales'].astype(str)
print(type(x[0]))
print(type(y[0]))
#print(x,y) ---- this gives me all the 20 values
#print(type(y[0]))
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

**Out Put / Error:**

  -

> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
>              AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>               in ()
>                    9 #print(type(y[0]))
>                   10 
>              ---> 11 plt.plot(x,y)
>                   12 plt.show()
>
> ```
>        /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py
>    in plot(*args, **kwargs)
>           3315                       mplDeprecation)
>           3316     try:
>        -> 3317         ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
>           3318     finally:
>           3319         ax._hold = washold
>
>        /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py
>    in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
>           1896                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
>           1897                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
>        -> 1898             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
>           1899         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
>           1900         if pre_doc is None:
>
>        /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py
>    in plot(self, *args, **kwargs)
>           1404         kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, _alias_map)
>           1405 
>        -> 1406         for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
>           1407             self.add_line(line)
>           1408             lines.append(line)
>
>        /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py
>    in _grab_next_args(self, *args, **kwargs)
>            405                 return
>            406             if len(remaining) <= 3:
>        --> 407                 for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
>            408                     yield seg
>            409                 return
>
>        /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py
>    in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
>            355         ret = []
>            356         if len(tup) > 1 and is_string_like(tup[-1]):
>        --> 357             linestyle, marker, color = _process_plot_format(tup[-1])
>            358             tup = tup[:-1]
>            359         elif len(tup) == 3:
>
>        /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py
>    in _process_plot_format(fmt)
>             92     # handle the multi char special cases and strip them from the
>             93     # string
>        ---> 94     if fmt.find('--') >= 0:
>             95         linestyle = '--'
>             96         fmt = fmt.replace('--', '')
>
>        /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py
>    in __getattr__(self, name)
>           3079             if name in self._info_axis:
>           3080                 return self[name]
>        -> 3081             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
>           3082 
>           3083     def __setattr__(self, name, value):
>
>        AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'find'
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following worked for me and hope it helps.... Issue was mixing differnt data types for plotting.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    pd_hr_data = pd.read_csv("/Users/pc/Downloads/HR_comma_sep.csv")
    take_ten_data = pd_hr_data[0:4]
    y = take_ten_data['average_montly_hours'].astype(int)
    x = [1,2,3,4] ----this is can be autogenerated based on the series/matrix size
    names = take_ten_data['sales']
    plt.bar(x,y, align='center')
    #plt.plot(x,y) ---- use this if you want 
    plt.xticks(x, names)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) with define `x` and `y` by columns names, because it better support plotting non numeric values:

```
take_ten_data = pd_hr_data[0:19]
x = take_ten_data['average_montly_hours'].astype(int)
y = take_ten_data['sales'].astype(str)

take_ten_data.plot(x='average_montly_hours', y='sales')
#working without x,y also, but less readable
#take_ten_data.plot('average_montly_hours','sales')
plt.show()
```

Sample:

```
take_ten_data = pd.DataFrame({'average_montly_hours':[3,10,12], 'sales':[10,20,30]})
x = take_ten_data['average_montly_hours'].astype(int)
y = take_ten_data['sales'].astype(str)

take_ten_data.plot(x='average_montly_hours', y='sales')
plt.show()
```

---

[image: graph]

But if all values are numeric it works nice:

```
take_ten_data = pd.DataFrame({'average_montly_hours':[3,10,12], 'sales':['10','20','30']})

x = take_ten_data['average_montly_hours'].astype(int)
#convert to int if necessary
y = take_ten_data['sales'].astype(int)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: So `x` and `y` variables are not required here.